# How to model ability bonuses so that options can be added/removed dynamically with Z3

Tags: z3

I would like to use Z3 to model character statistics in a game. For the sake of simplicity we'll focus on one stat: Armor Class (AC).

In this game characters can wear many types of armor, each of which has a different base armor class. In addition there are many other bonuses that can be added to armor. For simplicity lets consider the following

```
Armor Type | Base armor class
-----------|-----------------
Chain Mail | 16
Plate Mail | 18

Shield Type  | Armor Bonus
------------------------
Kite Shield  | +2
Magic Shield | +4

Defense Training | Bonus
-------------------------
Without          | +0
With             | +1
```

Characters can only benefit from one bonus of each kind, e.g. a character can only have one shield equipped at a time.

A character must have a shield in order to equip it, so the set of shields they can equip might change dynamically.

Additionally a character might acquire defense training at some point during play, (e.g. when leveling up) so the set of bonus types may change dynamically as well.

Players typically want the highest AC they can get for their characters, so a characters AC is the best base AC they can get plus the best bonus in each category for all the categories they have access to.

In an imperative/OO programming language I might model the system like this

```
class Character():
    base_armor_bonuses = [16, 18]
    shield_armor_bonuses = [2, 4]
    armor_class_bonuses: List[List[Int]] = [base_armor_bonuses, shield_armor_bonuses]

    def armor_class(armor_class_bonus_options):
        sum([max(bonus_kind) for bonus_kind in armor_class bonuses])

    def add_bonus_kind(new_bonus_options):
        armor_class_bonuses.append(new_bonus_options)

    def add_new_armor_type(new_armor_bonus):
        base_armor_bonuses.append(new_armor_bonus)
```

The imperative approach works fine for encoding these simple rules, however I am interested in quickly iterating on rule changes and new effects, so I'm hoping Z3 will enable a more flexible way of encoding these rules.

Additionally I'd like to use Z3 to explore the design space a bit, for example find the character build that maximizes armor class, which is hard to do with the imperative approach.

### Edit:

I would like to be able to use the system real-time to answer queries like "what is this characters current armor class?". Then in response to events that happen in-game, like a character getting a new shield, walking behind a wall, or taking off their armor, update the state of the world so that their armor class is updated for the next time I make the query "what is this characters armor class?".

I would also like to be able to answer, not necessarily in real time. What character, of all the possible characters you could make, has the highest armor class. This is easy with the simplified example, but enumerating all the possible characters to find the one with the highest armor class becomes infeasible once you introduce lots of kinds of characters all with access to different kinds of bonuses to armor class from various different options they can choose from.

For alternatives I've done some research on prolog, which might also be able to answer the queries, although I'm not sure what the performance differences might be. I've also considered a typical imperative program like the python snippet I included below. That would handle the real time queries well. However it would have the overhead associated with maintaining an imperative program that supported all the different options correctly. Additionally it would be difficult to impossible to determine the character with the maximum armor class or whatever from that program. I'm hoping a declarative logic language like z3 might overcome both of these limitations.

For now this is a hobby project for my friends and I to use when playing existing games (the real-time queries) and designing new games (non-real time queries).

### Edit 2

For the basic version, there are no free variables, it's essentially just calculating the Armor Class and other stats for a specific character. The reason I want to do this is because I don't want to maintain 2 separate systems with the rules of the game encoded, one for playing and one for designing.

For the more complicated example the free variables are the choices you make when building a character. Here's a simple example.

Characters have a base class Fighter, Archer or Wizard. Each time you level up you can take a level in any one of the classes, gaining the abilities of the lowest level of the class you don't already have. For example a Fighter 2/Archer 1 would have the first and second level abilities of a fighter and the first level abilities of the archer. Here are some sample abilities

```
level | fighter ability
----------------------
1     | Proficiency with Chain mail and the Kite Shield
2     | Defense Training or Proficiency with plate (players choice, i.e. a free variable)
3     | Defense Training or Proficiency with plate (whichever one they didn't get before)

level | wizard ability
-----------------------
1     | proficiency with Magic Shields
2     | proficiency with chain
```

So I would like to define the bonuses/options that are available to each character in a declarative way, and then ask Z3 what build has the highest armor class at level 3. Fighter 2 (for plate)/Wizard 1 is the best I can come up with for this small example with a total armor of 18 + 4 = 22.

Now if for example there were 12 character classes and each one had levels from 1 to 20 like 5th edition D&D. there would be 12^20 or roughly 2^71 possible level 20 character builds. Answering the question what level 20 character has the highest armor class by enumerating all the options would likely take longer than I'll be alive. This is where I'm hoping Z3 will be able to help.

### Edit 3

I am not sure what data structure/ type I should use to represent the armor available to a particular character. I thought about using arrays but I don't know how to express a statement like "the armor type array contains plate" when I define the fighter class option and then also express that there are no other unspecified elements in the array.

In other words I don't know how to define the contents of an array in such a way that they depend on the assignment of free variables (the character class level choices) and then later say there's nothing else in the array.

Additionally I'm not familiar enough with Z3 to even know if this is a good way of modeling the system.

Comment: It is not clear what question you are asking here. Can you clarify that aspect by editing your question? What kind of flexibility (i.e. constraints) would you like to encode with Z3? Can you make a concrete example? -- Do you mean to use this software in production? How large is your database of items? Do you expect real-time answers? What concrete alternatives have you considered to achieve your goal?

Comment: What are the *free variables* in the basic version of your problem? I don't see any. -- For the advanced version of your problem, why are you required to enumerate all possible characters instead of finding the best available item, for each category/type, and sum their scores up?

Comment: @PatrickTrentin Sorry it took me a few days to get back to this. I've updated the question to make the free variable, the players choice of character class at each level explicit with an example.

Comment: thank you for your edit. It is still unclear what kind of answer you are expecting to receive on this board: you stated what you would like to achieve, but not the problem you encountered when trying to do so.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin I've updated the question again. Hopefully it's clearer now what I don't understand how to do.

Comment: I would definitively not use SMT-LIB arrays, since these are used to model the dynamic behavior of arrays and not just as containers. Every item/skill/whatever A_i [A_i true if used, otherwise false] contributes either positively or negatively by a certain amount w_i to the value of the objective function, which is actually a Pseudo-Boolean SUM(A_i * w_i). If the character level ChL is under a certain threshold, some item/skill/whatever A_i cannot be used [ChL < LvL -> not(A_i)] ...

Comment: I would advice you to go read the online tutorial of Z3, and try testing out the syntax over some simple problems. Simple examples of managing and optimizing resources are also available [here](http://optimathsat.disi.unitn.it/pages/smt2examples.html), look at the "Linear Objective Combination" and the "Lexicographic Optimization" examples. The syntax is very similar to that of z3.